# Update field values of table with field values that is in query

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
UPDATE Tbl, Qry SET Tbl.Submit_Date = [Qry]![FirstOfTIMESTAMP]
WHERE (((Tbl.Info_ID)=[Qry]![INFO_ID]));
```

I want to update `Tbl.Submit_Date` with values from `[Qry]![FirstOfTIMESTAMP]` where both of their `info_id` are equal.

I get an error saying `Operation must have an updateable query`. I am using MSAccess. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Apparently I can only do it when both are tables. Lesson learned.

Comment: No, queries can be used but must be an updateable query. An aggregate query is not updateable. Saving calculated data, especially aggregate data, is usually not necessary nor advisable. Calculate when needed.

Comment: Are you able to add data to `Tbl` manually?  Either `tbl` or `qry` is locked for some reason (which is hard to diagnose without knowing more about the data involved, table structure and such.  Your first step should be Googling the error.  There are hundreds of forum questions and answers from people having (and solving) similar problems.

Comment: i think you can't update two tables at the same time...  therefore your syntax is wrong

Answer (score 0):

As you learned, in MS Access queries must be updateable in order to be used in `UPDATE` queries. As a workaround consider converting your SQL aggregation to domain aggregation with [DMin()](https://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/domain/dmin.php) assuming *FirstOfTIMESTAMP* is the `Min()` aggregation from a source table

```
UPDATE Tbl
SET Tbl.Submit_Date = DMin("TIMESTAMP","SrcTable","Info_ID=" & Tbl.[INFO_ID])
```